# Typo3 Search Indexed Engine Html Form

Tags: forms, search, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have Typo3 7.6 .
I have Search Indexed engine installed.
The page with form inside works.

My question is:
How do I generate the form html in other template?
I'm using fluid and vhs.

Thanks

Comment: Please, add more information on what are you trying to achieve. What other template are you referencing here, some custom plugin made by you or page template?

Comment: ok i have a template made by me. The plugin Search Indexed Engine use Form.html to print the form but when i copy the form in my header.html the "search[sword]" is not passed to the search page. Action works but search[sword] variable is not passed. I write only the tag form and the tag input textfield for search[word].

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue.

I have to define the right attributes "extensionName", "pluginName", "controller" on form outside its own template:

```
<f:form action="search" method="post" id="tx_indexedsearch" noCacheHash="true" extensionName="indexedsearch" pluginName="pi2" controller="Search">
```